# Responsive columns not working when hover effect added

Tags: html, css, hover, responsive

Thanks for reading. The problem with my code started when I added the hover effect on the images since then the layout stopped being responsive and images just clutter on top of each other when I resize the browser. Any help will be valued, since I am not able to find a solution since days :(

http://wall-e.blue/tobias/index.html

```css
#col_1 {
float:right;
padding: 3%;
width: 24%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto; }

#col_2 {
float: left;
padding: 3%;
width: 24%;
text-align:  left;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.wow {
position:relative;
width: 330px;
height:510px;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.wow img {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1
}
.overlay {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 1em;
color: black;
padding-top: 10px;
z-index:2;
opacity:0;

-webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.wow:hover > .overlay {
opacity:1;
width:560px;
height:310px height:auto;
}




@media all and (max-width : 768px) {

#col_1 {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 1%;
}
#col_2 {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 1%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<br>
<br>
<div id="title">
<span class="titulo" > Tobias Willmann</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class="mail" >  </span>
</div>
<div id="links">
<ul>
<li><a href="about.html"> About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<div id="col_1">
<div class="wow">
<img src="Katerinaneu_web.jpg" />
<div class="overlay">2016_hahahhaha</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<a href= "easter.html" > <img src= "easter_web.jpg" /> </a>
<div class="overlay">2016_nnn</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="col_2">
<div class="wow">
<img src="Marina_closeup.jpg" />
<div class="overlay">2015_nnn</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<img src="adriana_web.jpg" />
<div class="overlay">2015_i know you love</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: .wow class has width in **px** try change to 100%

Comment: thanks so much! this works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.wow {
  height:510px;
}
```

At Marina closeup
Makes the image go on top of the other image as I can see so far.